# How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

1. `webElement.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");`  This code is not working for me.
2. `String n = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ENTER);`
   `driver.findElement(By.id("open-tab")).sendKeys(n);`
   In which `key.chord` is not working for selenium C#.
3. `driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]);`   this one is also not working with my code.
   Is any alternative way available for switching tab.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Selenium 4 solution:**

```
driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab);
```

Note that it will open a new tab in the same window and will switch also to the newly opened tab.

to open a new window, you should use:

```
driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Window);
```

**Selenium 3 solution:**

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open()");
List<string> tabs = new List<string> (driver.WindowHandles);
driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[1]);
```